# Is "Respect to" Correct?

Tags: grammaticality

For example, can you rewrite the sentence "I respect my boss." as "I respect to my boss."?

Answer (score 1):

**Respect** is a transitive verb requiring a direct object. Accordingly, you should say:

> I respect my boss.

The word can also be used as a noun, in which case you often find "respect to", such as:

> I show respect to my boss.